# Materialize CSS Framework throws error

Tags: javascript, meteor, materialize

Running Meteor 1.1.6 with Materialize 0.96.1 and having no issues until I start up meteor one morning and get a white screen.  Console (firebug) says:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
var c = "input[type=text], input[type=passw
```

found in the generated file `materialize_materialize.js`

Stepping back in version history I can't seem to find anything glaring that I changed which might be the culprit.  Looking at the source code I found the code respective code but the line is actually terminated:

```
var c = "input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email], input[type=url], input[type=tel], input[type=number], input[type=search], textarea";
```

Anyone else ever see this issue, or have any ideas on how to fix it?

**Update:** Seems that Meteor is generating the file just fine but stops mid-string in the above error.  After the string cut off, the file continues with:

```
/* Exports */
if (typeof Package === 'undefined') Package = {};
Package['materialize:materialize'] = {
  Materialize: Materialize
};

})();
```

Oddly enough, this does not happen on my coworker's machine (he's using OSX 10.10.3, while I'm on Windows 7).

**2nd Update:** Also tested this issue on an Ubuntu 14.04 VM, and there were no issues - the app ran just fine.  Thinking it might have something to do with the Meteor version on Windows, I blew away my install, downloaded the installer, and re-installed Meteor on my machine.  What d'ya know, *it worked*.

Not going to mark this with an actual answer yet as I do not know what the cause of the issue is, other than something went wrong with Meteor itself - I think.

Comment: It’s most likely _not_ in that line but somewhere above or beneath it. What does JSHint say to the source code?

Comment: @Xufox tried throwing the source into JSHint.com but it blows up with too many errors.  Also had a work buddy try it out and it works on his machine just fine.  I thought it might be a caching issue with Firefox, but the same problem is on Chrome as well.

Comment: @Xufox also tried blowing the package away and starting fresh, which works as long as the `materialize:materialize` package isn't present.  As soon as I add it back in, the issue remains

Comment: If this happens again you can try to delete you ```.meteor/local``` folder, that way meteor will generate the files again and probably fix your error.

Comment: @Renews thanks for the tip - I'll definitely try that if this occurs again!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add a SASS package. I suggest `fourseven:scss`

Also, you could use `poetic:materialize-scss` instead of `materialize:materialize`.